# Are there any pre-Philostratus accounts of Apollonius of Tyana?

Tags: greek, source-request

I am interested in the life of Apollonius of Tyana, but the account by Philostratus seems a little late. Are there any other accounts of Apollonius outside Philostratus, either before him, or independent of him?

Comment: @Gibet Why aren't you posting that as an answer???

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure, check your closest copy of Pauly-Wissowa's article. (Your friendly Classics-literate librarian will know which encyclopedia I'm referring to.)

Answer (score 1):

So after digging around the web, I could really find any accounts of him before Philostratus. According to Wikipedia, the realist account of him was written by Philostratus. So unless we discover older writings or mentions of him, then no. This is the earliest ever written piece of him. And plus it is very detailed so be sure to check it out.